# Using Lightning Data Service not able to save custom lookup field on record creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service

Below is Lighting Component

```
<force:recordData aura:id="RecordCreator" 
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      targetRecord="{!v.newRecord}"
                      targetFields="{!v.simpleNewRecord}"
                      targetError="{!v.newRecordError}" 
                      fields=" Id, ParentId, custom_lookup__c"
                      />
```

Below id Controller.JS

```
component.set("v.simpleNewRecord.custom_lookup__c",component.get("v.userAccountInfo").Id);
    console.log("custom_lookup__c>>>"+component.get("v.simpleNewCase.custom_lookup__c"));
    component.set("v.simpleNewRecord.ParentId",component.get("v.Parent").Id);
    component.find("RecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {  
                    if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                           var resultsToast = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                           resultsToast.setParams({
                           "title": "Saved",
                           "message": "The record is saved."
                           });
                           resultsToast.fire();
                     }
```

I am getting value in

```
console.log("custom_lookup__c>>>"+component.get("v.simpleNewCase.custom_lookup__c"));
```

Below is Lightning UI component

```
<aura:attribute name="userAccountInfo" type="Account"/>

<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-4" >
        <lightning:input aura:id="customlookup" label="customlookup Name" value="{!v.userAccountInfo.Name}" disabled="true"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when record detail page is opened custom_Lookup__c value is blank.
Instead I am getting value for ParentId standard lookup field.
It is not saving custom_lookup__c value.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Probably you have mapped the fields wrong in the lightning component UI. Please Share your input elements of the UI.

Comment: I updated post, I want that field to be pre-populated with account name. and then save accountid to that customlookup field on saving record

Comment: also this is not correct as per mentioned code. console.log("custom_lookup__c>>>"+component.get("v.simpleNewCase.custom_lookup__c"));    it should be  console.log("custom_lookup__c>>>"+component.get("v.simpleNewRecord.custom_lookup__c"));

Answer (score 0):

you can check whether v.simpleNewRecord is having some value or not.It should not be null.

make sure you have defined the correct type for it.Just check the below sample code.

```
<aura:attribute name="boatReview" type="BoatReview__c" access="public"/>
<aura:attribute name="boatReviewRecord" type="Object" access="public"/>
 <force:recordData aura:id="service"
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.boatReviewRecord}"
                  targetFields="{!v.boatReview}"
                  fields="Id,Name,Comment__c,Boat__c"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.onRecordUpdated}"
                  />
```

in Controller you can do like this.

```
var rec = component.get("v.boatReview");
 alert("rec"+rec);
 component.find("service").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            if (!$A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(toast)) {
                toast.setParams({"title":"Saved",
                            "message":"The record was saved."}).fire();
            } else {
                alert("Successfully saved, question mark?");
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey I modified code so forgot to add updated aura:ID, Now its updated.

Comment: Try the edited code and see whether you are getting value for v.simpleNewRecord.make sure its not null.

Comment: On save I get all other field values except mentioned lookup field

Comment: make sure you are doing component.get("v.simpleNewRecord.custom_lookup__c") and not component.get("v.simpleNewCase.custom_lookup__c");